# Change each c# file in solution

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a tool or set of tools to go through a c# solution and automatically perform certain changes such as enforcing naming schemes and change for/foreach to linq if possible.

I have used Resharper to do some basic solution wide changes, but I would really like it to do more like global renaming.

Specifically, I would like a tool to rename method parameters to proper c# naming schemes. For instance, MethodA(string Field) should become MethodA(string field) and so on.

Comment: so you need a tool's name, something existing you do not want to make it yourself with code?

Comment: You should be a bit more descriptive of the exact changes you want, otherwise people are just going to guess at what you're trying to do, and the question won't be useful for other people when someone gets lucky and manages to answer your question.  Did you need to be able to do arbitrary macro-ish support, or did you need specific features?  Can you provide sample code showing the type of transformations you want to perform?

Comment: Specifically I have an entire code base where the method parameters all start with a capital letter. I would like to change them all to the proper naming scheme without doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper`s "Clean Up Code" tool can be run from context menu of any item in Solution Explorer. There are a few built in clean up configurations. You can configure your own. For example, you can set up order of fields\properties\methods\nested types in you class and reordering their before commit by executing clean up tool. It also can wrap its into region and so on.

Also you can force Resharper to use any of refactorings when cleaning up.(Optimize imports, remove unused methods or properties or use linq instead of loops, etc)

You can start looking from [there](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Index.html)

**UPD** You can use [stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) plugin to make your code correspond with the style conventions you want. It is open source and compatible with R#

Comment: Can you force resharper to rename a method parameter from MethodA(string Field) to MethodA(string field)?

Comment: The actual violation is SA1306 that I am finding and Stylecop does not do it automatically. It is a manual fix. http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReSharper%20Fixes

Comment: Stylecop is the tool to find code which should be changed. To make Resharper able to fix that code automatically in code clean up action use stylecop for resharper plug in. As I remember I used guide from [here](http://stylecop.forresharper.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Resharper has some pretty cool features, including "Cleanup Code", which can be run on multiple files at once.

It will automatically refactor your files based on the settings you've supplied it.

They have a demo version, so you can test to see if it helps with your problem.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: I would like method parameter renaming. Can resharper do that automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure. It will convert to upper/lower camel case, add/remove hungarian notation, etc... but I'm not sure if it will automatically choose "relevant" names based on the paramater type. If it cant do it alone, there may be a resharper pluggin/extension that can.